# Is there a Continuous Function mapping $\ S_1\ $ onto $\ S_2\ $

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, continuity, path-connected

> Let
>   $$
> S_1=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:1<x^2+y^2<2\}
> $$
>   $$
> S_2=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:2x^2<x^2+y^2<4\}
> $$
>   Is there a continuous function $f$ mapping $\ S_1\ $ onto $\ S_2\ $?

I believe that there is no function $f$ that maps $\ S_1\ $ onto $\ S_2\ $.

My reason for this is that while $S_1$ is path connected, $S_2$ is not path connected and $S_1\cap S_2$ is also not path connected. Hence you cannot map $S_1$ onto $S_2$. Is this logic correct? How can I build on this explanation?

Comment: Nice question! May I ask you why, $S2$ isnt path connected

Comment: If you graph $S_2$, it should be clear that no path can be drawn from one region to the other

Comment: Actually I dont understand, i can t draw the form of S2 in my head. How do you do this?  Sorry I m still a student :)

Comment: @MarineGalantin: An easy way to see this is to notice that the set is symmetric under $y\mapsto -y$ (thus has points both with $y>0$ and with $y<0$), but none of the points $(x,0)$ fulfills the inequality.

Comment: oh I see ! Thank you ! And is this set path connected ?  $$2x^2 \leq x^2 + y^2 < 4$$ Using your argument, trhought $(0,0)$

Comment: @MarineGalantin: To picture the set in your head, first note that the inequality is really two inequalities: $2x^2<x^2+y^2$ and $x^2+y^2<4$. The second one is just the open disk with radious $2$ around the origin. The first one can be simplified to $|x|<|y|$. Note that $|x|=|y|$ describes the two diagonals; $|x|<|y|$ therefore describes two open wedges around the $y$ axis. Since both inequalities are to be fulfilled at the same time, you get the intersetion of both; that is, two open pie slices, one above the origin, one below. The corners would beet at the origin, but are not part of the set.

Comment: @MarineGalantin: With $\le$ instead of $<$, the set is indeed path-connected, connecting the two pieces through $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you very much :) ! Have a nice day ! @celtschk

Comment: @MarineGalantin: You're welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right. The set $S_1$ is path-connected. Therefore, if $f$ is a continuous function whose domain is $S_1$, $f(S_1)$ is path-connected too. But $S_2$ is not path-connected, since $(0,\pm1)\in S_2$, but there is no element $(x,y)\in S_2$ such that $y=0$.

You can use the same argument using connectedness instead of path-connectedness.

Comment: Can this be generalised? For example, does a map from a connected set necessarily not map to a non-connected set?

Comment: Maybe you should add a little formal argument for why $S_2$ is not path connected (e.g. $\{y=0\}$ is a separating hyperplane)

Comment: @TashiWalde Done.